# Is there a nice way to use ui definition inside events in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

Consider following example:

```
ui: {
  name: '#name'
},
events: {
  'change #name' : function() { ... }
}
```

is there a way so I don't need to write #name selector in both places, since I could have changes in template in future?

Comment: If `ui` is not referentiable from some outer object no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question I got interested and here the result:

It's possible, you just need to move `events` to `intialize` like this

```
ui: {
  name: '#name'
},
initialize: function() {
  this.events = {};
  this.events["change " + this.ui.name] = function() { ... };
}
```